# How to limit TranscactionScope to given DataBaseContext in C#?

Tags: c#, transactions, transactionscope

I would like to be 100% that when I use such pattern

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    db1.Foo.InsertOnSubmit(new Foo()); // just an example
    db1.SubmitChanges();
    scope.Commit();
}
```

the transaction scope will only refer to db1 not db2 (db1 and db2 are DataBaseContext objects). So how to limit scope to db1 only?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The strength of `TransactionScope` is that it automatically catches everything within it, down the call stack (unless another `TransactionScope` with `RequiresNew` or `Supress`). If this is not what you want, you should use another mechanism for the transaction handling.

One way is to open `SqlConnection` and call `BeginTransaction` to get a transaction, then use that DB connection when creating your data context. (Maybe you'll have to set the Transaction propery on the data context, I'm not sure).

In the example you have given above, the use of a `TransactionScope` is totally redundant. There is only one function call that actually modifies the database: `SubmitChanges` and it always creates its own transaction if there isn't already one existing. The reason is that when you're doing several operations `SubmitChanges` should either succeed in them all or fail all. If you're only after transactional integrity for a single `SubmitChanges` call for a single data context, then you can just drop the `TransactionScope`.

Comment: This would be a slight problem, because I have already DB context. So it looks a bit odd -> DB context -> Connection -> DB context. I will try your approach though, thank you. About example, I know, it is just an example.

Comment: Why do you have a DB context already? The DB context is a very lightweight object that is usually created for each time it is used and disposed of immediately after `SubmitChanges`.

Comment: because it is passed to the function I write.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, what you are after is exactly what you have written, the compiler will ensure that transaction is completed when you commit.

Comment: Misunderstanding. I know that the transaction will be completed, but my question is -- how to "focus" only on db1? I don't want that db2 be involved.

Answer (score 0):

If you use:

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
{
    db1.Foo.InsertOnSubmit(new Foo()); // just an example
    db1.SubmitChanges();
    scope.Commit();
}
```

You can be sure a new transcation is created for this scope, so everyting you do inside the scope has its own transaction, and will never use any existing ambient transactions.

Comment: Could you please tell me how this prevent including db2 in transcaction scope "scope"?

Comment: @macias: Well, in theory 'scope' could fall inside another TransactionScope. Without 'RequiresNew', your scope would use the outer scope. So if this outer scope would use db2, they'd fall in the same scope. 'RequiresNew' prevents this.

Comment: the point is db2 can be used in the inner scope too. And I would like to prevent it.